# ionic platform add ios failed with output 254

Tags: ios, ionic2

when i am trying to add platform ios in my code its shows below errors:-

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@~4.4.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 254 Error output:
npm WARN @ionic-native/admob-free@3.4.4 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Comment: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/itr/Desktop/SK/cc/104/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo/node_modules/asap' -> '/Users/itr/Desktop/SK/cc/104/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo/node_modules/.asap.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent